# Firebase Android client loses authorization

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing and Android base Firebase application using basic email/password authorization.  On two of my phones it works fine (Nexus 5 and 5x).  On my Nexus 6 the the application authorizes successfully and downloads a large query, but then about 1 second the user becomes unauthorized (I'm monitoring via an AuthStateListener).   All the devices are using the same credentials.  The two Nexus 5's successfully operate at the same time.   Logging both of them out doesn't help the third phone.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: problem is not fixed to that one phone.  Moves to other phones and later the failing phones start working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and spent a great amount of time checking error code, exceptions and online solutions. Finally what for me was 'Clean build project and fresh installation!'